# How to get "string" away - replaced with "nothing"

Tags: customization, query-string

I am having - an issue respectively I like to try something:

with this code, I get the title from a product - respectively what is stored in the database, so far:

```
woocommerce_template_single_title();
$shaka_title = ob_get_clean();
```

The output is followed:

```
<H1 CLASS="PRODUCT_TITLE ENTRY-TITLE">FUN DIVING – 2 DIVE’S (AROUND KOH TAO)</H1>
```

What I need is only the "Name/Title" self - so just only

```
FUN DIVING – 2 DIVE’S (AROUND KOH TAO)
```

Without the `<h1...>` and `</h1>`

Any idea how I can do it?

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

The `woocommerce_template_single_title()` function calls to a template that uses this code:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

So it is just the product title, there is nothing that could go wrong here.

Check if you did not mess up output buffer, try using `the_title` function from above instead of ob and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi Greg36
Thank You for the answer. Somehow I understand what You mention. I am new in this kind of developing and coding.
So I am struggling with knowing how to do it.
I saw somewhere in the code this function the_title, but it seems to using in the theme as it is.

Possible to provide an example?

Regards,

Comment: To add some more information:

The original code is:

woocommerce_page_title();
$shaka_title = ob_get_clean();

I like to have - instead of the title of the "shop" - the title from the product.

Maybe there is another function I can use... But I did not found any other function.

Comment: So this code instead of displaying the name of the product, it displays the name of the shop / site?

Comment: If that is the case, to make `woocommerce_template_single_title()` display the title of the product it needs to be used inside the loop. What is the loop you can [learn here](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), it is a core concept to know to understand WordPress.

Comment: Hi Greg

I know - that it is a core concept to learn about it. I did a loads of pages with "pure" php/mysql.

Some months ago I started using Wordpress - and sure, first I bougth some themes - and customized them.

This here is also a theme I bought. But somehow some themes are just done for some "single" niche business and don't have what I need.

This is why I try to do things by myself.

Regards,
Simon